# "Property 'create' does not exist" in prisma client

Tags: node.js, prisma

I have an entity defined "Board" in prisma.schema like this:

```
model Board {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @ignore
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt @ignore
  title     String
  posts     Post[]
  Team      Team     @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id])
  teamId    String
}
```

After using prisma for a while, now the `prisma.board.create` function is unavailable (I think it was at around the time I added updatedAt)

I do have access to the rest of the functions, but trying to use `create` gives no autocomplete and this error:

> Property 'create' does not exist on type 'BoardDelegate'.ts(2339)

What am I doing wrong?
What are the usual cases for `create` not existing when the rest of the methods are there?

Comment: You should be able to work with `prisma.board.create(...)` not `prisma.create...`.

Comment: That's what I meant to say I was doing. All other functions are there (prisma.board.update, prisma.board.findMany, etc) but create isn't there

Comment: Which version of Prisma are you running and which experimental features do you have enabled, if any? Have you tried going through the generated client?

Comment: this issue still persists even if you generate. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I added "?" sign to these field and it worked:

```
model Board {
...
  createdAt DateTime? @default(now()) @ignore
  updatedAt DateTime? @updatedAt @ignore
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try doing the same but removing the @ignore from the createdAt field?
I had the same issue, prisma-client v2.25.0 and it fixed it.
If that's the case I think it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently a bug where `create` is lost [when adding `@ignore` to a not-null field](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11283).

As @Moshe mentions, you can make it optional first as a workaround.

In case you landed here looking for a way to safely delete columns with no downtime, here's what I do:

1. Mark the column optional and `@ignore`ed and remove all uses of the column in code
2. Drop the column

Answer (score -2):

Yup, you can find the documentation here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#create ( as mentioned by Pasindu Dilshan )

```
prisma.board.create({...})
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant on the question, the error shows up because `prisma.board.create()` does not exist